# Powershell - Run if statement against output of "$list = Get-StorageGroup -Identity $stgName.Name | Format-List -Property Recovery"

Tags: powershell

Objective is to find the recovery storage group.

```
$stg = Get-StorageGroup

foreach ($stgName in $stg )
{       

     $list = Get-StorageGroup -Identity $stgName.Name | Format-List -Property Recovery -Select-Object 



     if($list -match 'False')
        { 
            echo "Not" 
        }
     elseif($list -match 'True')
        { 
            echo "Yep" 
        }   
}
```

The result of the echo $list is: "Recovery : True".  Why can't I if($list -eq "Recovery : True") or match like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

|  I was able to get the result I wanted by changing the $list variable to:

```
$list =Get-StorageGroup -Identity $stgName.Name |   where {$_.recovery -eq 'True'}
```